# Browsable website while version-controled?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, svn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

I browsed around here on Stackoverflow and found this topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279/aspnet-visual-studio-and-subversion-how-to-integrate

However that didn't help me in my case, or i might just be a little stupid.

So to my problem!

Installed VisualSVN on a Server far far away and while this works perfectly, i can add my project and have a nice source control, i dont want to "manually" move my website to the correct place when im done, i want to map an IIS website to a cataloge on the SVN repo. where my site is stored.

Now this is my problem, i can't figure out if this is possible or not? The project is of course on my computer + the repo. and the repo-server and iis-server is the same machine, so i'd like to map those together, but i know that SVN uses some berkly-db-stuff on files..

Suggestions?

Comment: Subversion used Berkeley DB stuff in the past, but for many years the default has been to use FSFS because it is ultimately more robust. Either way, the Subversion server does not store your repository files in a directly usable format on disk. You must point your web server at a current checkout.

Comment: How would you set up a checkout that is file-based then?

Comment: All checkouts (made with "svn checkout") are file-based and can be directly used by a web server.

Comment: Can't find "svn checkout" anywhere.. hmm

Comment: If you want to make this an easier process look at CruiseControl.NET and NAnt. Once you setup a deployment project you can use the CC.NET tray application to perform a build and then publish your web site with a single click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible. The Berkeley DB is used at the repository side, but it doesn't really affect the client side. Subversion creates .svn folders everywhere, so if you don't like that use [rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/).

Edit: I missed the part you already have [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/). All you need is a Subversion client like [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) or command line svn on your web site to check out the web site.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a post-commit hook, they're small batch files that live in the repository's folders (there should be placeholder files in the hooks subfolder)

You set up the post commit hook to checkout the repository to a folder on your server and point your webserver to that same folder.

Comment: Also, make sure you're checking out using a proper user. I spent a whole day struggling with a post commit hook that didn't work, and it turned out that was what I missed.